# Mutually perpendicular unit vectors, one in same direction as a given

Tags: vectors

We have a given vector in the three-dimensional space. How do we find three other mutually perpendicular unit vectors, with the first of them being in the same direction as the given one? Thank you.

Comment: There are many choices in general for a given starting vector. Do you know how to find a unit vector in the same direction? Do you know Gram-Schmidt? Otherwise you could take another vector in a different direction and use cross products to find orthogonal vectors.

Comment: Can you at least find a unit vector parallel to the given one?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I can find a unit vector on the same line. But unless I'm mistaken, the way the question is formulated it seems that there is an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Yes, there are an infinite number of solutions. Once you find the unit vector in the direction of the given vector, any unit vector whose dot product with it is zero can be the second vector, and there are infinitely many such vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Thanks everyone, apparently the statement that was given to us was a bit vague hence the confusion.